# Angular http put through 404 for an existing and correct URL !!! from json server

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-http, json-server

I'm trying to apply Angular HTTP put using reactive forms for the first time. My problem is when I apply the following code I get an error of 404. The error indicates a server URL that is not found (XHR PUT http://localhost:3000/feedback). When I use the URL separately it brings data normally and the message that comes from the JSON server is 200 (GET /feedback 200 28.207 ms - 200). that means no problem with the URL !!! but still, get 404 in case of HTTP put

JSON server structure (i need to make put into "feedback": [])

```
{
  "dishes": [ ...
  ],
  "promotions": [ ...
  ],
  "leaders": [ ...
  ],
  "feedback": [
   {
      "firstname": "Ali",
      "lastname": "Sleam",
      "telnum": "123123123",
      "email": "Ali@gmail.com",
      "agree": false,
      "contacttype": "None",
      "message": "This is my message"
   }
  ]
}
```

feedback.service.ts

```
...
export class FeedbackService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }

    submitFeedback(feedBack: Feedback): Observable<Feedback> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
    return this.http.put<Feedback>('http://localhost:3000/feedback', feedBack, httpOptions);
  }

}
```

component.ts

```
...
feedbackForm: FormGroup;
feedback: Feedback;
contactType = ContactType;
...
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private feedbackService: FeedbackService) {
  this.createForm();
}
...
createForm() {
  this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25)] ],
    lastname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25)] ],
    telnum: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern] ],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
    agree: false,
    contacttype: 'None',
    message: ''
  });
}
...
onSubmit() {
  this.feedback = this.feedbackForm.value;

  this.feedbackService.submitFeedback(this.feedback) // <--- add to the server (put)
  .subscribe(feedback => { this.feedback = feedback; }, 
  errmess => { this.feedback = null; this.errMess = <any>errmess; });
}
```

component.html

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="feedbackForm" #fform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  ...
  <button type="submit" mat-button class="background-primary text-floral-white">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Update -- The feedback class

```
export class Feedback {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    telnum: number;
    email: string;
    agree: boolean;
    contacttype: string;
    message: string;
};

export const ContactType = ['None', 'Tel', 'Email'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to this problem, based on the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030845/json-server-getting-error-after-post-request)

JSON server needs an id whereas my class didn't include an id. It doesn't matter to assign a value for the id but it is necessary to include it at least in the class as follows.

```
export class Feedback {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the URL is working as a GET Request, instead of using `http.put`, try using `http.get`
This is not related to Angular. You are using a `PUT Request` to access a URL which is exposed as a `GET Request` in the server.
Since the Server doesn't know about the PUT Request, it sends 404.